# make tab in jquery function and add something to its parameter

Tags: jquery, html

I encountered with a challenge,I want to make Tab pages

This is my Tab button code:

```
<ul>
<li class="Tabs Active" id="Tab1" onclick="SetActive(Tab1)">
   <div>
        <span>Tab1</span>
   </div>
</li>
<li class="Tabs" id="Tab2" onclick="SetActive(Tab2)">
   <div>
        <span>Tab2</span>
   </div>
</li>
```

and This is Tab's page:

```
<div class="BodyBlock">
 <div class="Content">
     <div class="TabData" id="DataTab1">
        Tab1 Data
     </div>
     <div class="TabHidden TabData" id="DataTab2">
         Tab2 Data
     </div>
 </div>
```

And It's the function which show the page that user click on Tab button

```
function SetActive(id) {
    $('.Tabs').removeClass('Active');
    $(id).addClass('Active');
    $('.TabData').hide();
    $('Data'+id).show();
}
```

My proplem appears when I want to add 'Data' to id in SetActive function at line 4 when it added the tab button can not work correctly and the tab pages don't show
I use of jquery v3.2.1

Comment: try `$("#" + id).addClass('Active')`

Comment: I am thankful with your guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget *#* in last line. See following code

```
function SetActive(id) {
    $('.Tabs').removeClass('Active');
    $(id).addClass('Active');
    $('.TabData').hide();
    $('#Data'+id).show();
}
```

You also forget single quote **SetActive('Tab1')** and **SetActive('Tab2')**

```
<li class="Tabs" id="Tab2" onclick="SetActive('Tab1')">

<li class="Tabs" id="Tab2" onclick="SetActive('Tab2')">
```

Comment: Now try here is the link  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LLoLJy?editors=1010

Comment: you need a `#` in here also `$("#"+id).addClass('Active');`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `#` to these 2 lines `$(id).addClass('Active')` and `$('Data'+id).show();`

Take a look at the example below, i made your code work

```css
.Tabs.Active { color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="Tabs Active" id="Tab1" onclick="SetActive('Tab1')">
   <div>
        <span>Tab1</span>
   </div>
</li>
<li class="Tabs" id="Tab2" onclick="SetActive('Tab2');">
   <div>
        <span>Tab2</span>
   </div>
</li>

<div class="BodyBlock">
 <div class="Content">
     <div class="TabData" id="DataTab1">
        Tab1 Data
     </div>
     <div class="TabHidden TabData" id="DataTab2">
         Tab2 Data
     </div>
 </div>

<script>
function SetActive(id) {
    $('.Tabs').removeClass('Active');
    $("#" + id).addClass('Active');
    $('.TabData').hide();
    $('#Data'+id).show();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for you tips

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct the line #4:

```
$('#Data'+id).show();
```

Comment: Hope this one fixed your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay Being first to answer dont mean you get an upvote, Also there is more problems that just the one you pointed out.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, I know mate, being first does not mean it must get up vote. But the answer which got best answer tick and upvote is the same solution which I gave.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay no he found more problems than you did, thats why he got accepted.